# Laravel jquery javascript localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Problem is my `timer` was working as well. But when i save `timer`s `value` to localStorage. I just want to when user refresh `timer` wont stop and resume when stopped at.

**javascript**

```
function startTimer() {
var presentTime = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML;
var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
var m = timeArray[0];
var s = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
if(s==59){m=m-1}
if(m<0){ document.myform.submit(); }

document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =
    m + ":" + s;
setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);

var startTime = document.getElementById("timer").value;
localStorage.setItem("startTime", startTime);
//alert(startTime);
}

function Dahin(){
    var startTime = localStorage.getItem("startTime");
    document.getElementById('timer').value = startTime;
}
```

**in my view**

```
<h3 onload="Dahin();" class="page-title">Шалгалтын 50 асуулт</h3><h4><div>Үлдсэн хугацаа = <span id="timer">{{ $time }}</span></div></h4>
```

**Update fixed timer**

now how to save timer value to sessionstorage and retrieve when refresh page

Comment: is your timer time is same with your `new Date()` time?

Comment: No its not. `<span id="timer">30:00</span>` its being like this. Problem is how to save timer `value` to `localstorage`

Comment: when you use `alert(startTime)`. what does it return?

Comment: null, null, null each second

Comment: what is this? `var presentTime = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML;`. I think this variable will return html tag.. what do you expect from this variable?

Comment: I found that timer example from Jfiddle and little changed it. It works as well. Just cant save `timer` value to localStorage each second.

Comment: I have posted my answer, you can try it ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let change your code:

```
var check = localStorage.getItem("startTime");
var startTime = check ? check : document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML;
document.getElementById('timer').value = startTime;

function Dahin(){
    localStorage.setItem("startTime", startTime);
}
```

the problem why you get null is because you use `.value`. You put your time into span tag. `.value` is only work for input field

Comment: Yeah bro. `Alert` shows now timer. But i think its not saving into `localStorage`. How do i save time into `localStorage`?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working too. But i appreciate your kindness and answer.

Comment: Can I know what is dahin function? and when it call?

Comment: `onload="dahin();"` I'm just calling it on view `onload` then i take `saved time` back from `localStorage`.

Comment: I think the problem is on your onload.. lets try to move your onload in body tag  `<body onload="Dahin()">`